# How to solve a differential equation like this one?

Tags: differential-equations

Does anyone know how to solve this equation in Mathematica

`dx/dt = f(x) + u`

where

`f(x) = -x, if x < 1 or x = 1`

Comment: Look at Piecewise to define the function and at DSolve for the solution of the differential equation.

Comment: I have written Dsolve[x'[t] == u + f[x], x[t], t] but I don't know how to continue. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Try `DSolve` instead of Dsolve.  You can look up the help file by typing `?DSolve`.

Comment: It's my mistake! I have written DSolve, my problem is how we solve the equation when we have the condition "x<1 or x=1".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"$x<1$ or $x=1$" is simply $x\le1$. I'm assuming that $f(x)=0$ for $x>1$; please specify if this is not true.

```
f[x_] = Piecewise[{{-x, x <= 1}, {0, x > 0}}];
```

Solve the differential equation:

```
DSolve[x'[t] == f[x[t]] + u, x[t], t]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!!!!